# Setting up a local server using a domain socket with python?

Tags: python, sockets

I would like to set up a server on my computer and have another process on my computer connect to the server using a domain socket. I've looked at various python guides but I can't seem to find a straight answer! Here's my code this far.

Client:

```
import socket;
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
s.connect("8888")
```

Server:

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = 'host', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)
print 'Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT
while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print request

    http_response = """\
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Hello, World!
"""
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
    client_connection.close()
```

I get the following error when running the server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webServer.py", line 7, in <module>
    listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: argument must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple
```

Comment: well, the complete error stack would be more helpful rather than looking for what line generates this error in your code, but basically, this is saying that you have to extrct the value from the tuple as a string or read-only character buffer rather than pass a tuple as an argument

Comment: Ok, I edited it to include the entire error stack

Comment: Unix domain sockets don't have port numbers. http://blog.eduardofleury.com/archives/2007/09/13 ; although it looks like you don't want Unix domain sockets at all, Python comes with a HTTP server - "SimpleHTTPServer" - http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Comment: I definitely do want Unix domain sockets. I'm writing code for two processes to communicate within product of ours using a domain socket, and to start things off I want to connect to a domain socket on my mac. EDIT: To clarify, the reason why there is HTTP on there is because I took some of the code from online xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question you ask about the error you're getting, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) says:

> A single string is used for the AF_UNIX address family. A pair (host, port) is used for the AF_INET address family

And the mentionned string is the Unix socket filename. For Unix sockets, forget about host and port.

So you should change:

```
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

into (for instance)

```
listen_socket.bind(SOCKET_ID)
```

and accordingly define `SOCKET_ID` as a file name, like `/tmp/my_socket` (for instance, maybe using [a temporary file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) is better, not sure). And whatever it is, you should define it in one place, instead of hard coding it in two different files.

There might be other things to say about the complete code you put in your question, but they don't belong to the question.